# Как сделать не циклом

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Добрый день. Такая проблема: есть два датафрейма в питоне - в первом датафрейме два столбца (широта и долгота), во втором -  пять столбцов (координаты северной границы региона, координаты южной границы региона, координаты западной границы региона, координаты восточной границы региона, непосредственно сам порядковый номер региона).

В чем суть задачи: нужно посмотреть какой регион (из второго датафрейма) соответствует координатам из первого датафрейма и в первый датафрейм добавить столбец с этим регионом

Проблема: Я знаю как это сделать с помощью циклов, НО значений в первом датафрейме десятки миллионов, а кол-во регионов во втором датафрейме 2500. То есть это очень долго.

Есть ли наиболее простой способ это сделать?

Первый датафрейм - data,там ширина и долгота это столбцы pickup_longitude   pickup_latitude

regions - второй датафрейм откуда нужно взять регион

[image: Код]

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных (3-7 строк).

Comment: Добавил принтскрин в описание

Comment: Я не вижу как это можно сделать "векторизированным" (без цикла) путем. Можно при помощи `DataFrame.apply(..., axis=1)`, но это тот же цикл...